# Populating list of Firebase database in Angular Dart

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, angular-dart

Trying to learn from https://dart.academy/build-a-real-time-chat-web-app-with-dart-angular-2-and-firebase-3/, but while implementation

- **Error-1**

  while debug `GET http://localhost:56991/main.dart 404 (Not Found)`
- **Error-2**

  [image]

firebase_service.dart

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;
import 'package:yns_admin/category_component/category.dart';

@Injectable()
class FirebaseService {

  fb.Database fbDatabase;
  fb.DatabaseReference databaseReference;

  List<Category> categories;

  FirebaseService() {
    fb.initializeApp(
      apiKey: "AIzaSyBOShlCgUeqTL99n32ssasasasasa",
      authDomain: "yns-app.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://yns-app.firebaseio.com",
      storageBucket: "yns-app.appspot.com",
    );

    fbDatabase = fb.database();
    databaseReference = fbDatabase.ref("categories");
  }

  void showCategories() {
    categories = [];
    databaseReference.onChildAdded.listen(newCategory);
  }

  void newCategory(fb.QueryEvent event) {

    Category category = new Category.fromMap(event.snapshot.val());
    categories.add(category);
  }
}
```

Map code comes from
category.dart

```
  class Category {

  final String categoryTitle;

  Category(this.categoryTitle);

  Category.fromMap(Map map, this.categoryTitle) {}

  Map toMap() =>{
    "categoryTitle":categoryTitle
  };
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:yns_admin/app_component/app_component.dart';

void main() {
  bootstrap(AppComponent);
}
```

Comment: Where does `fromMap()` come from? Are you using the `json_serializable` package?

Comment: I have added the map code with category.dart

Comment: Your `fromMap(...)` expects 2 values, but you're only passing one `event.snapshot.val()`. Your `fromMap(...)` doesn't seem to do anything with the expected `Map` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: `http://localhost:56991/main.dart` should be 404, that's intended behavior. If you just access `http://localhost:56991`, you should see your component. For more info about this, check out [Angular Dart official doc](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/architecture).

Q2: I think you need to modify your `new Category.fromMap()` function to check just the snapshot value. Not sure exactly how you would do it, but it should be fairly easy.